# Angular-2 : Copy one object to another

Tags: angular

I wants to copy my class object to temp object.

**Class properties:**

```
export class PageModel {       
    AppID: any = null;
    ParentID: any = null;
    Type: any = null;
    Order: any = null;
    IsEnabled: boolean = false;
    View: any = null;
    Toolbars: any = null;
    Attachments: any = null;
}
```

**My initial object :**

```
pageModel : PageModel =new PageModel();
pageModel.Type='New';
pageModel.Order=1;
```

Now i wants to assign this updated object to any **temp object**, this temp object is going to assign as **model in one of the form**, so only on Save button click i wants to update my main object.

I just need help, how to copy main object to temp one.

Comment: How about `Object.assign()`?

Comment: it support two way binding, if i change in temp model also affect in main one

Comment: i miss the {} as parameter in Object.assign()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tempObject = Object.assign({}, tempObject, pageModel);
```

This will create a new object,  assign all properties of tempObject to it and then assign all properties of pageModel to it.

Comment: If i have single object as above it work perfect, but in case of list of object then Object.assign not work, have you any idea?

Comment: Try `tempList = Object.assign([], tempList, pageModels);`

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer is perfect for this problem. but some cases it's not work properly like as

`{ a: 0 , b: { c: 0}}` ;

so you can use, it's also work for deep clone

```
tempObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pageModel));
```

Please see the bellow example:

```
let obj1 = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
  let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}

  obj1.a = 1;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}

  obj2.a = 2;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { a: 2, b: { c: 0}}

  obj2.b.c = 3;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { a: 1, b: { c: 3}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { a: 2, b: { c: 3}}

  // Deep Clone
  obj1 = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
  let obj3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
  obj1.a = 4;
  obj1.b.c = 4;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}
```

for more info please visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assignhttp://)